# Consume web service in C# with digital sign the request

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, soap, certificate

I need to consume a web service (SOAP) in C# with digital sign the request. But everytime I got the 400 bad request with message that "The Login failed because of an exception: javax.security.auth.login.LoginException: CWWSS6810E: The runtime can not identify the key corresponding to the identifier [Xqgkv4YNXYZgUmgtTX+s+ffshm4=].</" Here is my code:

```
public BSCACustomWcfServiceClient(string clientCertificatePath, string pfxCertificatePath)
        {
            clientCertificate = new X509Certificate2(clientCertificatePath);
            pfxCertificate = new X509Certificate2(pfxCertificatePath, "BlueShieldCa2022!");
        }

        public string GetClientList()
        {
            System.ServiceModel.Channels.AsymmetricSecurityBindingElement asbe = new AsymmetricSecurityBindingElement();
            asbe.MessageSecurityVersion = MessageSecurityVersion.WSSecurity10WSTrustFebruary2005WSSecureConversationFebruary2005WSSecurityPolicy11BasicSecurityProfile10;

            asbe.InitiatorTokenParameters = new System.ServiceModel.Security.Tokens.X509SecurityTokenParameters { InclusionMode = SecurityTokenInclusionMode.Never };
            asbe.RecipientTokenParameters = new System.ServiceModel.Security.Tokens.X509SecurityTokenParameters { InclusionMode = SecurityTokenInclusionMode.Never };
            asbe.MessageProtectionOrder = System.ServiceModel.Security.MessageProtectionOrder.EncryptBeforeSign;

            asbe.SecurityHeaderLayout = SecurityHeaderLayout.Strict;
            asbe.IncludeTimestamp = true;
            asbe.DefaultAlgorithmSuite = System.ServiceModel.Security.SecurityAlgorithmSuite.Basic128;

            CustomBinding myBinding = new CustomBinding();
            myBinding.Elements.Add(asbe);
            myBinding.Elements.Add(new TextMessageEncodingBindingElement(MessageVersion.Soap12, Encoding.UTF8));

            HttpsTransportBindingElement httpsBindingElement = new HttpsTransportBindingElement();
            httpsBindingElement.RequireClientCertificate = true;
            myBinding.Elements.Add(httpsBindingElement);

            Uri httpUri = new Uri("uri");
            EndpointAddress endPoint = new EndpointAddress(httpUri);

            ServiceReference1.ReportsClient cliente = new ServiceReference1.ReportsClient(myBinding, endPoint);

            cliente.Endpoint.Contract.ProtectionLevel = ProtectionLevel.None;
            cliente.ClientCredentials.ServiceCertificate.Authentication.CertificateValidationMode = X509CertificateValidationMode.None;

            cliente.ClientCredentials.ServiceCertificate.DefaultCertificate = clientCertificate;
            cliente.ClientCredentials.ClientCertificate.Certificate = pfxCertificate;

            cliente.Open();

            string ReportName = "MCP Client Listing";
            string ReportType = "TAB";
            string TimeStamp = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ss.fffZ");
            string SenderId = "CMSZZ00573";
            string SenderName = "MY TEST ORGANIZATION";
            string OrganizationId = "9999";
            string ReceiverId = "DHCS CMS NET";
            string Payload = "MCP Client Listing";
            byte[] Payload1;
            string ErrorCode;
            string ErrorMessage;

            var res = cliente.ClientListEnvelope(ref ReportName, ref ReportType, ref TimeStamp, ref SenderId, SenderName, ref OrganizationId, ref ReceiverId, Payload, out Payload1, out ErrorCode, out ErrorMessage);

            return null;

        }
```

Can anyone help to resolve the issue?

Comment: Looks like code under the hood is doing an http request to get info.  The request is failing to make a connection due to a credential issue.  Do you get back any info? Which line is failing.  Are you an Admin?  If running inside VS than you do not have Admin privilege.  You have to start VS by right click on VS shortcut and select Run As Admin.

Comment: cliente.ClientListEnvelope failed. I got the response from server that says idnetifier cannot identify the key

Comment: It looks like you are trying to get a list from the server.  You are failing due to credentials.  The exception says "javax.security.auth.login.LoginException".  It is not TLS since you are getting a response 400.  If TLS fails then you never send out the request.  AUTH usually means that OAUTH is failing.   It looks like there is a key name in the certificate and the certificate is not loaded on server.  This is a guess.